# Revalidate primary domain for Google Apps for Business

Tags: gmail, google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-business, google-search-console

I am setting up Google Apps for Business for a client.  They had someone set it up previously for and it has sat there dormant not being used. When they validated the primary domain they did so via the 'upload HTML file to website' approach as described - [here](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=63026).

Anyhow this seems to rely on the HTML file being left in the domain root permanently which I don't like the sound of in case someone accidentally does something with it. I would much prefer to use the validate domain via editing the DNS record which seems more solid.  But can't seem to find how to change it or revalidate it in the Google Apps for Business interface.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to change the way you validate a domain name. Proceed to [Webmasters Central](https://www.google.com/webmasters/verification/home?hl=en&theme=cpanel&authuser=1) and there will be links to the verification details of every domain attached to your account (provided that it is the same account that added the domains to the system). Clicking on it will bring you to a page with more details on the domain. There is an option "Verify using a different method.", using it will guide you through verifying your domain using an alternative method.

Comment: knew the setting had to be hidden in there somewhere - thanks